# Raspberry Pi 4 EEPROM (and USB firmware) configurations

Tags: pi-4, bootloader, pi4-eeprom

A while ago, the Pi Foundation mentioned that there was an update for the USB driver (yes, apparently more components on the board have firmware above and beyond drivers loaded by the OS) to reduce heating... but that makes some USB devices not work properly.

1. Has there been any success in fixing the USB driver bug, and how do I find future updates? The testing driver was simply dropped in a forum post in the middle of a topic, and I don't see forums as a good way to be sure you've actually found the most recent version (short of reading through **every** post for info).
2. Is it capable of auto-updating, or is this something I must manually find on the forum and install? If it can auto-update, what package do I install to add this?

The Raspberry Pi 4 also has the bootloader EEPROM, which is somewhat unfamiliar to me. I have an older image, and I'd rather not lose its data by getting the latest one with all the updater programs.

3. Similarly, what package provides rpi-eeprom-config and rpi-eeprom-update? I have an older image that is not updated, but I don't want to dump it and start over.
4. What is in the EEPROM's config? There were previously two boot config files in the /boot directory, and (correct me if I'm wrong) one of them was replaced by the EEPROM config (but is still there). How much of that is necessary?
5. The repair tool can replace the bootloader even if it's corrupted. How can it do that if the bootloader is the part that's broken? (And if it can boot without the bootloader, what exactly is the point of it)
6. Where are the schematics for both config eeproms and the connections to the USB driver? I'm curious as to how this all works on a peripheral level.(let me know if this question--or others--are out of scope)

Comment: 1. Check raspberrypi.org, 2. check raspberrypi.org 3. latest rasbian includes packages called rpi-eeprom and rpi-eeprom-images - this should be enough to keep eeprom images up to date

Comment: *the bootloader is entirely unnecessary* - the bootloader in RPi4 is in the eeprom, essentially replacing `/boot/bootcode.bin` - so, no, it's not unnecessary - as for whatever config options exist within the eeprom bootloader, they are NOT replacement for `/boot/config.txt` - not sure what you want to change in the bootloader

Comment: By the way - Bootloader config - https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/hardware/raspberrypi/bcm2711_bootloader_config.md - found by searching for the phrase *rpi4 bootloader configuration*

Comment: Your question is to broad. Please ask only one question. There is no problem to create multiple questions.

Comment: Apparently there have been updates--I can confirm that the page wasn't there last I checked. I see that they did add the utility and auto-update then. Not sure how I feel about that. The schematic still doesn't seem to list the info on where the chips are, how to hardware write-protect them (if that's a thing), and how the USB chip works, though...

Also, I will edit  my question accordingly.